# Differential equations book

Tags: textbooks, reference-books, differential-equations

I am looking for a book on differential equations (ordinary/partial) of a particular kind. I figure out I am terrible at solving differential equations. This a vast field and unfortunately I don't really have time to study that in depth now. And the terrible thing is that I forget everything very quickly. The dream book right now would be :

- I encounter a differential equation to solve.
- Most of time, the resolution is simple but still, I fail.
- I open the book where tens of typical equations are solved, possibly with different techniques. Techniques should be emphasized more than theory.
- When I forget one resolution, I can easily find back in the book how to tackle it again.

This way I am hoping learn and get used progressively to the most common equations I am facing in my work (wave propagation, diffusion, reaction rates...)

Thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: this book, it sounds like the MSE :)

Comment: Sorry? Googling MSE doesn't help much.

Comment: I've never used it, but it sounds like [Schaum's Outline of Differential Equations](http://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-Differential-Equations-Series/dp/0071611622) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Héhé that looks pretty nice indeed

Comment: @David In reference to James Cook's comment: math.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is software which computes most of the solutions to diff EQs which people can compute by hand.  For example, http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=e602dcdecb1843943960b5197efd3f2a

Comment: @StevenGubkin, they are able to solve loads of equations I've never dreamed could be solved. And yes, leave the routine tasks to the computer. Better concentrate on the qualitative aspects, those aren't automatable (yet?), and apply equally to equations that *can't* be solved analytically and have you grab a numerical tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this pdf book for differential equations .
 https://www.math.ust.hk/~machas/differential-equations.pdf.
It has also the important formulas and questions with examples.

Answer (score -1):

For basics: A Course in Ordinary Differential Equations - 
Bindhyachal Rai, ‎D. P. Choudhury, ‎Herbert I. Freedman

Comment: Can you describe how this book meets the OP's requirements? They asked for a specific kind of a DE book.

Comment: Which edition do you mean: the first or the second? The first has a good 3.7 out of 5 stars at Amazon.com, but the second edition has a poor 2 out of 5.

Comment: ISBN: 0849309921. don't know about first or second edition. Please help yourself.